# SQL filtering by Average

Tags: sql

i have two tables products and reviews
each product has several reviews linked by a foreign-key product_id in the reviews table
additionally each review has a field called rating with a decimal value
i wish to get the names of all products whose average rating is above a certain threshold
something in the lines of

```
SELECT p.name
FROM products p
INNER JOIN reviews r ON p.id = r.product_id
WHERE avg(r.rating) > 3
```

MySQL is not letting me use the avg function in the where clause.
How do I do something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use 'having'

```
SELECT p.name, avg(r.rating) as average
FROM products p
INNER JOIN reviews r ON p.id = r.product_id
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING avg(r.rating) > 3
```

Comment: woops - I missed the 'GROUP BY' - fixed

Comment: That's why sometime the HAVING clause is referred to as 'the WHERE clause of groups'

Comment: That takes a lot longer to say than 'having' :)

Comment: Yes, but once you learn that moniker you never forget when to use WHERE and when HAVING